# Determine which Application Load Balancer is attached with which Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have several Elastic Beanstalk applications, each with an Application Load Balancer attached. I can't seem to figure out how to determine which ALB is attached to which EB. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the **Tags** for the Application Load Balancer, you will find the *environment id* and *name* over there which is given to the Elastic BeanStalk application. By using these Tags, you can easily determine which ALB is attached to which EB.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have thought. Just to be certain I just now rebuilt that environment, and the new ALB does not have any tags associated with it. I may have some sort of deeper issue here.